# How to rewrite a url onlick in JQUERY? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have 4 divs that when clicked, it goes to a URL...

**Problem:** When **div winkel_name** is clicked... the page is redirected with additional details. For example: the store page location is: www.rootdomain/store/ ...

When div winkel_hover is clicked... it goes to **www.rootdomain//store/storename/**
How can i **rewrite and sanitize** the url to this output: www.rootdomain/store/storename ?

```
<div class="winkel_hover">
   <table width="100%" height="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <div class="winkel_name">
                            <h2><a href="<?=$arItem["CODE"]?>"><?=$arItem['NAME']?></a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<div class="winkel_name">
     <h2><a href="s-hertogenbosch"><font><font class="">'S-Hertogenbosch</font></font></a></h2>
</div>
```

While the javascript to make the url for winkel_hover is this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.winkel_hover').click(function(){
    var winkel_url = $(this).find('.winkel_name a').attr('href');
    window.location.href = winkel_url;
});
</script>
```

Please help me to sanitize my url to this output: www.rootdomain/store/storename  ?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is what your looking for. In the click function just write this line and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.winkel_hover').click(function(){
      var winkel_url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
      window.location.href = winkel_url.substring(1);
   });
</script
```

Comment: Hi Viswanath.. Thanks for the reply.. It still wont work.. it still goes to www.rootdomain//store/storename/ ... I need www.rootdomain/store/storename as this kind of output...

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now check it, works well perfectly

Answer (score 0):

How about a sanitise function?

```
function sanitise(url) {
  out = url.replace('//', '/').split('');
  out.pop();
  return out.join('');
}
```

**USAGE**

```
var winkel_url = sanitise($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgsvw8gk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.winkel_hover a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var winkel_url = $('.winkel_hover .winkel_name a').attr('href');
        window.location.href = winkel_url;
    });
});
```

As for sanitizating, I wouldn't do it client side as it can be made void if anyone tries slightly. Make sure you sanitize any get parameters server side.

Answer (score -1):

For the first look I can't see why it has the extra slash. Ensure your href does not contain slash at the beginning, e.g it's 'url' and not '/url';

As a 'hack' solution you can just remove it: 
$(this).find('.winkel_name a').attr('href').replace('/','');